# Read and write list to IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to simply save a list of strings to isolated storage on windows phone 8. I have simply created a list and save it this way:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

List<String> projectList = new List<String>();

projectList.add("yo");

settings.add("yo", projectList");

settings.Save();
```

How do i read this data from IsolatedStorage and put it into the same list once the app starts up again? I'm looking for a simple method - which i haven't found on the web, i haven't managed to implement any of the solutions i found on the web, as they use different methods.

Please help, and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just cast the setting back into a List. I usually add a helper function to read settings, to prevent reading something that isn't saved:

```
private static object readSetting(string key)
{
    return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(key) ? IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key] : null;
}
```

You could use that function to restore your List, for example like this:

```
List<String> projectList = readSetting("yo") != null ? (List<String>)readSetting("yo") : new List<String>();
```

Comment: I used this solution, but i cant access the settings from within the readSetting() method

Comment: That's because I took it from a helper class of mine. Sorry about that. Does the updated method work?

Comment: I can access "settings", after return and after the question mark, it says this: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property namespace.mainPage.settings

Comment: Yep sorry about that. I took the method from a class of mine where `settings` equals `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`. The updated solution should work.

Comment: aaa, then i get it - it works perfectly now, thanks!