# How to write/read an object in the storage of my Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I cannot figure out what is the mechanism of writing/reading an object in the application store of my WP8.1 app and when I reopen the app to read that object? Any code samples you have?

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data

Comment: This will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164784/read-and-write-list-to-isolatedstorage-in-windows-phone-8